# Need to store previous element value in for-each condition while writing XSL formula

Tags: xslt

Need help where i have scenario like
Ranges

```
R1 for year 2000 ti 2001 is 0 to 10
R2 fir year. 2001 to 2002 is 0 to 10
R3. for year 2002 to 2003 is 0 to 10
R4 fir year.  2003-2004 is 20 to 30
```

Then it would show as

```
Range 2000 to 2003 0 to 10
Range 2003 to 2004  20 to 30
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with XSLT? Wouldn't RegEx be a better fit?

Comment: No the only option is to use xsl to transform  this from xml.

Comment: But there is no XML in your question... And no attempt in XSLT to solve it... Read about [mcve].

Comment: Yeah i have the scenario defined is from cml

Comment: If your input is XML then show us an XML input. Also explain the logic that you want to apply here - your example is not at all clear.